# ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials using AppEngine dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

When I do :

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
```

in my main.py which is served using the App Engine development server, I am getting an error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
```

When I ran from a standard python console the same statement, I am not getting any error. The import works fine.

I confirm that I have pyopenssl installed on my system. I have already read this post which suggest only to install it: [ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063124/importerror-cannot-import-name-signedjwtassertioncredentials)

Any idea of what's wrong with the development server?

PS : My main goal is to connect to BigQuery

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063124/importerror-cannot-import-name-signedjwtassertioncredentials)

Comment: @Pentium10 I noticed already this other thread. However, I have pyopenssl installed an it is working properly in the python console. My issue is specifically with Google App Engine.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests example code in google documentation

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` and deploying your PKCS12 key with your application, you can use `AppAssertionCredentials` from the `oauth2client.appengine` package. Ensure that your appengine application service is added to your project and you are good to go.

Looks like a long standing issue with the AppEngine environment: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=133