# Connecting to Google Analytics API using Python

Tags: python, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have tried to follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) to connect to Google Analytics API. I have followed the instructions, step by step. I have Python 2.7 installed on my computer. I have installed Google client library. When I run the program, i get the following error in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HelloAnalytics.py", line 6, in <module>
    from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredential
ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
```

The line 6 that it referring to is:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
```

I am at a complete lost. I looked at others who have had the same error, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063124/importerror-cannot-import-name-signedjwtassertioncredentials), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191213/importerror-cannot-import-name-signedjwtassertioncredentials-using-appengine-de), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733897/import-error-google-analytics-api-authorization), but the solutions did not work. I have some programming knowledge, but compared to many of you, I am a noob.

The full code is here:

```
"""A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API."""

import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools



def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location,
                service_account_email):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list auth scopes to authorize for the application.
    key_file_location: The path to a valid service account p12 key file.
    service_account_email: The service account email address.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """

  f = open(key_file_location, 'rb')
  key = f.read()
  f.close()

  credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(service_account_email, key,
    scope=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service


def get_first_profile_id(service):
  # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

  # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

  if accounts.get('items'):
    # Get the first Google Analytics account.
    account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

    # Get a list of all the properties for the first account.
    properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
        accountId=account).execute()

    if properties.get('items'):
      # Get the first property id.
      property = properties.get('items')[0].get('id')

      # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
      profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
          accountId=account,
          webPropertyId=property).execute()

      if profiles.get('items'):
        # return the first view (profile) id.
        return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

  return None


def get_results(service, profile_id):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
  # for the number of sessions within the past seven days.
  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()


def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
    print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
    print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

  else:
    print 'No results found'


def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Use the developer console and replace the values with your
  # service account email and relative location of your key file.
  service_account_email = '<Replace with your service account email address.>'
  key_file_location = '<Replace with /path/to/generated/client_secrets.p12>'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(get_results(service, profile))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [source repository](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) was recently updated, and the [Hello Analytics Guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) have since also been updated to make use of the new code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

...
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)
```

Where `service_account_email` is the email address of the service account you get from the dev console, and the `key_file_locaiton` is `/the/path/to/key.p12`, and `scopes` are the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/authorization#OAuth2Authorizing) you need to grant to the service account.

Please remember to add the service account email address as an authorized user of the Google Analytics view (profile) to which you wish it to have access.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the update. But now I get this error: TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\New folder (3)\HelloAnalytics.py", line 112, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\u6023273\Desktop\New folder (3)\HelloAnalytics.py", line 106, in main
    service_account_email)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\New folder (3)\HelloAnalytics.py", line 35, in get_service
    service_account_email, key, scopes=scope)

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 272, in from_p12_keyfile
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_obj:
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

Comment: There was an error in the sample which has since been corrected. You need to remove the portion which reads the file. Thew new call is simply `  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile( service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)` where key_file_locaiton is simply the filename.